# How to filter nested JSON values?

Tags: java, collections, java-8, jackson, java-stream

I have a JSON file like below. I want to read all the values and check if the input string contains one of the JSON values, the return true. But with my try, always it returns `false`.

```json
{
  "RECORDS": [
    {
      "word": "word1",
      "language": "en"
    },
    {
      "word": "word2",
      "language": "en"
    },
    {
      "word": "word3",
      "language": "en"
    }
  ]
}
```

**My method**

```java
 public static boolean check(String content) throws IOException {
        File file = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:sample.json");

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Map<?, ?> map = mapper.readValue(file, Map.class);
        for (Map.Entry<?, ?> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            if (content.contains(entry.getValue().toString())) {
                return true;
            } else
                return false;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: `return true` interrupts the loop iteration for, and from the functions you are always returned at the very bottom `return false`

Comment: Seems the problems is on the `.contains()` comparison. What kind of result that you want? If you want to check that `content` is exist in the json, the condition should be: `entry.getValue().toString().contains(content)`.

Comment: @Dharma `entry.getValue().toString().contains(content)` only works when content is exactly equals to the json values. If content is a paragraph then is returns false again.

Comment: @SeniorFullstack can you suggest to me how to solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
return mapper.readValue(file, new TypeReference<Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>>>() {})
             .values()
             .stream()
             .flatMap(List::stream)
             .map(Map::values)
             .flatMap(Collection::stream)
             .anyMatch(content::contains);
```

---

The code snippet above will check whether your `content` string contains any of the nested values (e.g. `word1`, `en`, `word2` ...)

---

If you're looking for values of the `word` field only, then try the following:

```
return mapper.readValue("", new TypeReference<Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>>>() {})
             .values()
             .stream()
             .flatMap(List::stream)
             .map(m -> m.get("word"))
             .anyMatch(content::contains);
```

Comment: Thank you, But it gives me an error in part `Map<String, Map<String, String>>(){})` , It says `'>' or ',' expected`

Comment: In both ways, It throws an exception            `Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of java.util.LinkedHashMap<java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object> out of START_ARRAY token
`

Comment: @FaramarzAfzali Right, I missed the nested `List<>` out there. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`for (Map.Entry<?, ?> entry : map.entrySet())` will get you a LinkedHashMap Entry. So basically, your entry variable will look something like this:

[image]

for your code to work, you will need to iterate over the values again before doing the `contains` check

Comment: Thanks, @Hasham Rasheed, Now I have the JSON objects like this `[{word=word1, language=en}, {word=word2, language=en}, {word=word3, language=en},` How can I extract the `word` value to check that input contains it or not??